# Running a Workflow instance for a specific time using workflow foundation

Tags: workflow

Let me explain the scenario.  I want to start a workflow instance which will create a request approval process. There are different levels and each level has approvers and specific time is assigned for each level. An approver should approve within the given time to complete process or he/she may be alert again to approve once the assigned time of the level is over.

A user may request something by starting a approval process this would intiate a workflow which will create a workflow instance for the specific request. when the process starts it will inform the respective approvers in first level to approve the request made by a user. if a approver failed to approve within the given level time the approver will be alerted to approve the request and it should pause the workflow and wait for it. if he managed to approve the request the process should moved to the next level and continue with the same process until the number of levels are over.

Can i do this using windows workflow foundation. I read and understood that invoking a workflow, bookmarks can be used for this. i need to how can i manged the background timer for each level and alert the users. im stucked at that point please help me.

if there is a better solution please feel free to talk :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by using a Pick activity which has a timer (delay) activity and your custom approval activity inside. Pick activity will choose only one PickBranch to complete when ever either of the contained activity is completed. That said if the timer activity is triggered, the custom approval activity will be cancelled then. And you can choose to do what ever you what to do afterward such as sending emails to notify the involved approvers that the task was expired. WF has a lot of potential but it seems this technology has been left in the corner by its vendor for a while...